# Convert CONCAT from SQLServer to Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

I have script at MSSQL server that I need to convert to Redshift

Here is part of it

```
  CROSS JOIN (
SELECT        MONTH(be.TimeWorkedFrom) AS MONTH,
                YEAR(be.TimeWorkedFrom) AS YEAR,
                CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH, be.TimeWorkedFrom),'/',1,'/',DATEPART(YEAR, be.TimeWorkedFrom))AS MonthBilled
FROM            BE2_Billing_Entries be

WHERE           be.TimeWorkedFrom > '1/1/2015'
                AND be.ProviderId = 65277

GROUP BY        MONTH(be.TimeWorkedFrom),
                YEAR(be.TimeWorkedFrom),
                CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH, be.TimeWorkedFrom),'/',1,'/',DATEPART(YEAR, be.TimeWorkedFrom))
                )t
```

I rewrite it like this

```
  CROSS JOIN (
SELECT          DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom) AS MONTH,
                DATE_TRUNC('YEAR',be.timeworkedfrom) AS YEAR,
                CONCAT(DATE_PART('MONTH', be.timeworkedfrom),'/',1,'/',DATE_PART('YEAR', be.timeworkedfrom))AS MonthBilled
FROM            billing_entries be

WHERE           be.timeworkedfrom > '1/1/2015'
                AND be.providerid = 65277

GROUP BY        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom),
                DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom),
                CONCAT(DATE_PART('MONTH', be.timeworkedfrom),'/',1,'/',DATE_PART('YEAR', be.timeworkedfrom))
                )t
```

But now I get error

> [42883][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: function concat(double precision, "unknown", integer, "unknown", double precision) does not exist; java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: Amazon Invalid operation: function concat(double precision, "unknown", integer, "unknown", double precision) does not exist;

Where can be my problem?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be using `CONCAT` in a query because it's a view-level concern (and separate data values should be returned to the client with their original data-types). Is there a reason you need to do `CONCAT` in SQL instead of in your application? I also note that using `CONCAT` in a `GROUP BY` does not give you the best performance (and it's unnecessary in your example as you're already using the two underlying values (month and year from `TimeWorkedFrom`) in your `GROUP BY` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use || (Concatenation) Operator - redshift support this operator or nested 
concat - for your reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_concat_op.html

```
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT          DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom) AS MONTH,
                DATE_TRUNC('YEAR',be.timeworkedfrom) AS YEAR,
                DATE_PART('MONTH', be.timeworkedfrom)||'/'||1||'/'||DATE_PART('YEAR', be.timeworkedfrom) AS MonthBilled
FROM            billing_entries be

WHERE           be.timeworkedfrom > '1/1/2015'
                AND be.providerid = 65277

GROUP BY        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom),
                DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom),
                DATE_PART('MONTH', be.timeworkedfrom)||'/'||1||'/'||DATE_PART('YEAR', be.timeworkedfrom)
```

Comment: Hm. now I get this error

`Invalid operation: column "be.timeworkedfrom" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;`

Comment: But, how I can do this? I newer in sql

Comment: use that column in group by clause like GROUP BY        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom),
                DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',be.timeworkedfrom),
                DATE_PART('MONTH', be.timeworkedfrom)||'/'||1||'/'||DATE_PART('YEAR', be.timeworkedfrom), be.timeworkedfrom